# choosing digest and encryption algorithm for pkcs7 in openssl

Tags: c++, cryptography, openssl, digital-signature, pkcs#7

I am trying to implement Digital Signature (PKCS7) capability using OpenSSL (version 1.0.1).

I am relatively knew to this.

Using the APIs: ***PKCS7_sign*** and ***PKCS7_verify***,
I don't know how to set a particular digest and/or encryption algorithm for signing.

*PKCS7_sign* in turn calls ***PKCS7_sign_add_signer***, whose 4th parameter which represents the digest identifier, has been hard-coded as NULL. This will mean that the default digest algorithm will be used.

So my questions are:

1) What are the digest and encryption algorithms that are used by default?

2) Is there any way to set these defaults? How can that be done?

3) Suppose I sign some data and send it to other party. How will it know the default algorithms used in the signing? [Answered]

Comment: 1) check the documentation, 2) they are set, thats why they're defaults, but you can surely override them to whatever you want (like SHA256 ex.),  and finally 3) read the PKCS7 specification. the signing algorithm and digest algorithm are included by OID as part of the [PKCS#7 Cryptographic Message Syntax Standard](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2129) format.

Comment: Also, relating to (1), in the notes of the documentation for PKCS7_sign, "If a signer is specified it will use the default digest for the signing algorithm. This is SHA1 for both RSA and DSA keys."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default digest algorithm is SHA-1, per the [OpenSSL documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/PKCS7_sign.html).

The "default" algorithm used for signing is determined by the type of key present in the x509 certificate you pass in for the `signkey` parameter.  Generally speaking, this is going to be an RSA key, but it can also be a DSA key.